# What are the benefits of locally small categories? And question on diagram chasing

Tags: category-theory

There are some theorems proven from diagram chasing. However, all the proofs I saw was proving those statements when objects are all sets. In this case, this category is locally small, but not all locally small categories have objects as sets. So I think "locally small" category should be named for subcategories of **Set**.

For example, when proving snake lemma, we do a digram chasing. However, when proving this theorem, we pick elements and chase the diagram. That is, we prove it by assuming that all objects are sets **and** $Hom(A,B)$ is a subset of $B^A$. Let call this condition, the condition-@. (Note that this condition is even stronger than small category)

In an arbitrary category, when $f:A\rightarrow B$ is an epimorphism, we cannot simply *pick* an element of $B$ and *choose* and element of $A$ that is mapped to the element of $B$ under $f$. Indeed, the phrase "element of $B$" is nonsense since we don't know what $B$ is. So I do not get why we need locally small categories. It seems too general that most arguments cannot be applied.

Secondly, it is said everywhere that Snake lemma and Five lemma and etc can be proven in any abelian category, but I don't get how the usual diagram chasing argument can be applied to prove those when a given category does not satisfy the condition-@.

Of course, the snake lemma holds for the category of chain complexes of $R$-Mods, namely $Ch(R-Mod)$, but this category does not satisfy the condition-@, since $Hom(C,D)$ is no more a subset of $D^C$. However, the same idea of diagram chasing can be applied to this category to prove the snake lemma.

So is there a condition that generalizes the condition-@, so that we can apply diagram chasing argument to all kinds of $Ch(Ch(....Ch(R-Mod)...))$?

Comment: Relevant: [Mitchell's Embedding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell%27s_embedding_theorem)

Comment: @Hayden So, it implies that small abelian categories can be seen as $R-Mod$ category. What about locally small abelian category?

Comment: Wikipedia says that a cathegory is *small* if $\text{obj}(C)$ is a set, which is different from every object being a set: for instance, $\text{Set}$ and $\text{Vec}$ are not small. According to this definition, condition-$@$ is not stronger than it.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Small categories need not satisfy that $Hom(A,B)$ is a subset of $B^A$.

Comment: I know. My point was that categories satisfying condition-$@$ need not be small.

Comment: There's nothing about the snake lemma that requires talking about elements of objects or assuming that the morphisms are set-functions. Local smallness simply says that $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ is a set for any $A,B$; it involves no statement about what sort of thing the morphisms are. Also, $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)\subset B^A$ isn't the same as being a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$; $\mathbf{Grp}$ has this property, and is far from being a subcategory of $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Snake lemma itself does not require that, but I mean its proof requires that. Do you have any reference which proves snake lemma not requiring the condition-@?

Comment: @Rubertos - Sure, there's Borceux's *Handbook of Categorical Algebra* vol II, p48.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine Thank you!

Comment: For a category $\mathcal{C}$, the $\mathrm{hom}$-sets defines a bifunctor $\mathcal{C}^{op}\times \mathcal{C}\to\mathbf{Set}$ if and only if $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small. In which case, there exists an embedding $\mathcal{C}\hookrightarrow \mathbf{Set}^{\mathcal{C}^{op}}$, called the [Yoneda embedding](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Yoneda+embedding), which allows us to think of an object $C\in \mathcal{C}$ as a presheaf of sets $\mathrm{h}_C$.